# Stenciljs assets not accessible in reactjs application

Tags: reactjs, safari, base64, stenciljs, svg-sprite

#### Current Behavior

Hi,

In stenciljs i am building a design system where i have huge amount of icons so i have created a svg sprite file.

#### Steps to Reproduce

Method1 :
Tried importing the svg sprite file and calling it with id is converting to base64 format which is not supported in safari.

import altiIcons from "../../assets/altiIcons.svg";
<use
xlinkHref={`${altiIcons}#Search`}
href={`${altiIcons}#Search`}>

2. Method 2:
   In this method gave the path directly which is perfectly working in chrome and safari when i run in stenciljs.

Related code:

<use
xlinkHref={`/assets/altiIcons.svg#Search`}
href={`/assets/altiIcons.svg#Search`}>

so now as this method 2 is working i published it and tried using this component in react but not able to see the icon as the path is checking in react but not on stenciljs. Please help . I need to resolve immediately .

Thanks Mounika

#### Expected Behavior

Ultimately the icon must work in all browsers

#### System Info

```
MAC
```

Expectation: need to work in all browsers

#### Stencil Version

2.22.3